# No Installation candidates found for gitolite

Tags: apt, 16.04, git

I am trying to install git and gitolite with the command `sudo apt-get -y install git gitolite`. It gives me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package gitolite is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'gitolite' has no installation candidate
```

I tried updating apt-get, but that didn't do anything. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Xenial Xerus:

```
andrew@athens:~$ apt-cache search gitolite
gitolite3 - SSH-based gatekeeper for git repositories (version 3)
git-notifier - git commit email notification script
andrew@athens:~$
```

So your command should be:

```
sudo apt-get install git gitolite3
```

This has changed from older versions of Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume you guessed the package name correctly!

```
$ apt-cache search git | grep lite
gitolite3 - SSH-based gatekeeper for git repositories (version 3)
gitolite - SSH-based gatekeeper for git repositories
icewm-lite - wonderful Win95-OS/2-Motif-like window manager
```

(I see `gitolite` because I'm on 14.04) YMMV